# How to get npm v5 install a dependency I just updated manually in package.json?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

In my node.js project, I used to change version numbers of dependencies in the `package.json` file and then run `npm install` or `npm update` to install the configured versions.

However, since I'm using npm v5 this seems not to work anymore - neither an install nor update actually installs the updated versions. I'm running node.js v8.1.3 and npm v5.0.4.

Now I more and more resort to a terrible workaround to force npm to actually update depencencies, simply deleting and reinstalling all dependencies:

```
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json && npm install
```

This sort of feels like a bug rather than intended behavior. Any idea on how to get npm v5 working "normally"?

UPDATE:

looks like npm v5 indeed has a bug: `npm update` doesn't update `devDependencies`, see https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/16901

Comment: Maybe you want to take a look at [npm-check-updates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates).

Comment: @pzaenger yes I use npm-check-updates all the time, works like a charm. Only npm v5 forgets to update dev dependencies according to changes in package.json...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a correct NPM@5.x behaviour. You should use a command line for manipulating with packages.

**Case 1**

You need the latest versions of all packages. Use `npm update` inside the folder.

**Case 2**

You need the latest version of package `package-one` and `package-two`. Use `npm update package-one package-two`.

**Case 3**
You need the specific version of package `package-one` and `package-two`. Use `npm install package-one@a.b.c package-two@x.y.z`.

At any case the command will update `package.json`, `package-lock.json` files and `node_module` folder.

Comment: Thanks @galkin for your clear explanation, Case 1 is indeed what I want and expect. After more digging it looks like `npm update` works as expected for `dependencies`, but there is a (known) bug in npm@5 for updating `devDependencies`, see https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/16901.

Answer (score 0):

to install a specific version of the module you can specify it in the npm install command, and --save will also add it to your package.json.
this way works for me on node 8.0.0 and npm 5.0.0, (upgrades and downgrades versions)

```
npm install --save <module>@<version>
```

Comment: npm@5 `--save` flag is true by default.